# Mysqlでの集計について

Tags: mysql, sql

以下のSQLで集計を行おうとしておりますが、要件として売り上げがない日(0円)の
データも出力したいのですが、どのようにするのがよいでしょうか？
できれば、データベース側で完結したいです。

```
2014/12/1 ¥10000
2014/12/2 ¥10000
2014/12/3  ＊このレコードは存在していないですが、リストで　2014/12/3 ¥0と出力したい。
2014/12/4 ¥10000
```

sql

```
select
    DATE_FORMAT(s.start_date, '%Y-%m-%d') as date,
    sum(p.price) as price
from
    sales s
inner join
    products p
on
    s.product_id = p.id     
group by
    DATE_FORMAT(s.start_date, '%Y%m%d');
```

Answer (score 2):

すいません、最初の回答は勘違いしていました。

salesの方にない日付も出力したいということですね。

日付テーブルを別途用意するしかないかと思います。

---

[**本家の方で同様の質問**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157282/generate-days-from-date-range)があり、以下で日付テーブルを生成できるようです。

ループも一時表も使わずに生成しています。
ただし、curdateを使っている関係からか、古い日付だと取得できないことがあるようです。
（私の環境ですと2011年だと結果が空に）。

```
select a.Date 
from (
    select curdate() - INTERVAL (a.a + (10 * b.a) + (100 * c.a)) DAY as Date
    from (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as a
    cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as b
    cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as c
) a
where a.Date between '2014-12-20' and '2014-12-27'
```

---

都度作成では問題になる場合（パフォーマンスまたはSQLの見た目の問題など）のために、
カレンダーテーブルを作成するプロシージャのサンプルを作成してみました。(mysql 5.1.59)

以下の様なテーブルに、年と日付を指定してその月の日付を投入します。
day列は数値ではなくdatetimeであることに注意してください。

```
create table mycalendar (year integer, month integer, day datetime)
```

後で示しているプロシージャを作成後、年月を指定して呼び出すと mycalendar テーブルにデータを投入します。

```
call sampleInsertDaysToMyCalendar(2010,2)
```

コメントで書いていますが、3行入れ替えると月の指定を無視して 1年分のテーブル作成に変更できます。

テーブルとプロシージャの作成を一気に行うコードは以下の通り（データの投入はコメントアウトしています。）。
phpmyadminで実行できることを確認しています。

```
delimiter //

-- テーブルが無ければ作成します。
create table if not exists mycalendar (year integer, month integer, day datetime) 
//

-- プロシージャが存在すれば削除します。
drop procedure if exists sampleInsertDaysToMyCalendar
//

-- プロシージャの作成部分です。
CREATE PROCEDURE sampleInsertDaysToMyCalendar(IN _year integer, IN _month integer)
BEGIN
  set @curday = date_add(makedate(_year,1), interval (_month)-1 month);
  set @lastday = last_day(@curday);

  delete from mycalendar where year = _year and month = _month;

  -- 月を無視して、年のデータを入れたい場合、上の3行と下のコメントアウトしている3行を入れ替えます。
  -- set @curday = makedate(_year,1);
  -- set @lastday = last_day(date_add(@curday, interval (12)-1 month));
  -- delete from mycalendar where year = _year;  

  commit;

  while @curday <= @lastday do
     insert into mycalendar (year, month, day) values (_year, _month, @curday);
     set @curday = ADDDATE(@curday, 1);
  end while;
  commit;

END
//


-- プロシージャを実行します。
-- call sampleInsertDaysToMyCalendar(2010,2) //

-- デリミタを ;に。
delimiter ;
```

Comment: 説明不足で申し訳ありません。    
      
要するに上記SQLだとレコードがない場合の日付は、  
出力されません。  
http://doruby.kbmj.com/hotdog/20140129/Oracle_  
上記サイトにある内容をMysqlで実装したいと考えております。

Comment: @YuzoUrakami こちらこそすみません、加えて日付テーブルをその場で用意する方法ということですか？でしたら、それも質問に加えた方がいいと思います。（「別の日付テーブルを用意したくない」など）

Comment: そうですね。ありがとうございます。
やはり日付テーブルを用意してそれに対してleft joinしたいと思います。

大変恐縮なのですが、カレンダーテーブル作成について
具体的な方法をご存じであればご教示いただけないでしょうか？

Comment: @YuzoUrakami 本家のほうにあった日付データ作成を追記しました。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
教示いただいた内容で試してみたいと思います。

Comment: @YuzoUrakami あらかじめ作成しておいても問題がない場合のために作成するプロシージャのサンプルを追記しました。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
勉強になりました。